# Continuity of a function after forcing f(-x) = -f(x)

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Suppose that $f : \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous function, and define the function $f_{sym} : \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ by picking a vector $a \in \mathbb{R}^n$ with $a_i \neq 0$ for all $i \in [n]$ and setting
$$f_{sym}(x) := \begin{cases} f(x) &\mbox{ if } a^Tx \geq 0 \\ -f(-x) &\mbox{ otherwise}  \end{cases}$$
Can we conclude that $f_{sym}$ is continuous as well?

Any help would be great, thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider $n=1$, $f(x)=e^x$, $a=1$, then
$$g(x)=f_{sym}(x)=
\begin{cases}
e^x&x\geq0,\\
-e^{-x}&x<0.
\end{cases}$$
Clearly, $\lim_{x\to0^+}g(x)=1$ and $\lim_{x\to0^-}g(x)=-1$.